# Installation failed: Connection to the phone failed. Check the IP and that developer mode is active

Tags: iphone, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

I think the pebble documentation at https://developer.getpebble.com/2/getting-started/hello-world/ isn't specific enough when it comes to how to enable app deployment. Perhaps it is simply out of date post 2.0. I wasted an hour on this with some other q&a's out there leading me down the wrong path so I am going to try and save others some time, hopefully they just google the error message and find this q&a.

see answer to my own qtn below

Answer (score 2):

so the site (as of the time i am writing) says: "On iOS, open the Settings application and enable the Developer Mode option. Open the Pebble application, and in the status screen click on Developer Connection, and enable the remote connection. Take note of your phone IP address."

what they want you to do is to go on to your iPhone -> Settings -> Pebble -> Developer Mode and enable that. THEN go into the Pebble iphone app and hit the menu and you will see a new tab on at the bottom saying DEVELOPER (OFF). go ahead and set that to on. it will then tell you your IP (no need to hunt around in the Settings again for it). now you can publish.

other q&a's will tell you to toggle the developer mode on and off, or to restart your router. try my way first.